# int to String in Android

Tags: android, string

I get the id of resource like so:

```
int test = (context.getResourceId("raw.testc3"));
```

I want to get it's id and put it into a string. How can I do this? .toString does not work.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
String testString = Integer.toString(test);
```

Answer (score 25):

Or you can use Use

> String.valueOf()

eg.

```
int test=5;
String testString = String.valueOf(test);
```

Answer (score 5):

Very fast to do it if you dnt remember or dnt have time to type long text :

```
int a= 100;

String s = ""+a;
```

Comment: While this is easier to code, it's not efficient for memory or speed, so putting lots of these in a class can "bloat" the memory usage and run slower than if you're using the object specific methods

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
int a = 100;

String s = String.format("%d", a);
```

Comment: This is what i am warned to do