# Android: Convert int to String

Tags: java, android, string, int

Is there an equivalent for `getString()` that works for integers?

I have some integer values passing into a function and eventually placing in a SQLite table.

```
x.getString() //works for string values
```

works for string values, but doesn't work for integer values.

Below is my code:

```
Employee createdEmployee = employeeDAO.createEmployee(
    address.toString(),
    phoneNumber.toString(),
    salary //this is an integer value and getting error
);
```

Comment: Use `toString()` or use `""+ salary`

Comment: Please do a research before asking a question. This has already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071040/java-convert-integer-to-string and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839642/android-int-to-string

Comment: I figured it out.  This is what I was looking for.

    int sal = Integer.valueOf(salary.toString());

Answer (score 2):

You can insert salary as a string but whenever you want to use salary as a integer..
then you can use

```
Integer.parseInt(salary);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options:

1- Use helper method defined in `String` class to convert various objects including `int` to `string`:

```
Employee createdEmployee = employeeDAO.createEmployee(
                address.toString(),
                phoneNumber.toString(),
                String.valueOf(salary)
        );
```

2- Simply append an empty string to the `int` which would implicitly convert int to string:

```
Employee createdEmployee = employeeDAO.createEmployee(
                address.toString(),
                phoneNumber.toString(),
                salary + ""
        );
```

3- Use helper method defined in `Integer` class to `string` to `int`:

```
Employee createdEmployee = employeeDAO.createEmployee(
                address.toString(),
                phoneNumber.toString(),
                Integer.parseInt(salary)
        );
```

Comment: Reason for down voting please ?

Comment: Because 3 is identical to gunjan's answer

Comment: @BroSlow and you realise that gunjan answered 5 mins after me.. :)

Comment: That part of your answer was added 6 minutes after his....