# int value to Textview

Tags: android

I am trying to set a int value along with some  text to textview, but it is not coming.

```
myTextView.setText(getText(R.string.remaining_count) +" " + count);
```

here count is integer variable.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Please have a look of my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839642/android-int-to-string - take look

Answer (score 1):

Please try this -

```
myTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.remaining_count) +" " + count);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

both of these..

```
String testString = Integer.toString(test);
```

or

```
int test=5;
String testString = String.valueOf(test);
```

then set this to textView
happy coding... :)

Answer (score -1):

Try below code.

```
myTextView.setText(getString(R.string.remaining_count) +" " + String.valueOf(count));
```

Or

You can also append value behind text which you mention in string.xml

```
<string name="remaining_count">Remaning Count : %1$s </string>

mTextViewTotalBalance.setText(getString(R.string.remaining_count, count));
```

[Check this link for more info.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

Comment: %1$s what exactly it indicates?

Comment: @user3860600 check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling